# A sintaxe do Python tanto aceita "+" quanto "," no comando "print()"?

Tags: python-3.x

Por exemplo, se eu quiser imprimir uma string que eu crio na hora junto com uma variável já pronta, qualquer um dos casos funcionaria?

---

**#Caso 1**

```
nome = "Júlia"

print("Olá " + nome)
```

---

**#Caso 2**

```
nome = "Júlia"

print("Olá ",nome)
```

Answer (score 7):

"+" e "," no print, são duas coisas bem diferentes "por baixo do capô" em Python - embora o resultado possa ser parecido ou até o mesmo.

É importante entender o que acontece - e porquê "vale dos dois jeitos", e até mesmo entender jeitos ainda melhores.

Primeiro: o `print` em Python 3 não é um "comando" (era em Python 2). Ele é uma função - igual a qualquer função que você defina em seu programa.

E, funções em Python, podem ter que receber um número exato de parâmetros, ou podem receber um número variável de parâmetros - isso é parte da linguagem.

No caso, o `print` é uma função que recebe um número variável de parâmetros em sequência. O que ele faz é: converter cada parâmetro para uma string (lá dentro ele chama `str(parametro)` ), e escrever no arquivo especial `sys.stdout` esses parâmetros, intercalados por espaço (a string " ").  Tanto esse separador, como o arquivo de saída do print, podem ser modificados por parâmetros com nome ("sep" e "file") - mais pra frente falo disso.

Já o operador "+" concatena strings! Ou seja, se você faz `"nome: " + variavel` isso vai criar uma única string, resultado da expressão - e essa string é passada como um único parâmetro para o "print". O mais importante aí é que o "+" funciona tanto dentro dos parênteses do `print`, como em qualquer ponto do programa - é simplesmente uma expressão em Python, assim como a expressão `2 + 2` - que é transformado em "4" quando é executada.

Na prática, se os dois operandos forem strings, quase tanto faz na hora de chamar o "print" (mas tem a diferença que, por padrão, a separação dos parâmetros com `,` introduz o espaço de separação).

Exemplos:

```
>>> a = "Júlia"
>>> print ("nome", a)
nome Júlia
>>> print("nome" + a)
nomeJúlia
>>> print ("nome", a, sep="****")
nome****Júlia
>>> print("nome" + a, sep="****")
nomeJúlia
>>> b = "nome" + a
>>> print(b)
nomeJúlia
>>> print ("idade:", 23)
idade: 23
>>> print ("idade:" +  23)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

**Outra forma de interpolar valores em strings**

A partir do Python 3.6, no entanto, foi criada uma nova sintaxe que torna muito mais prática  a colocação de valores de variáveis (e outras expressões de Python), dentro de textos - são as "f-strings". A mesma coisa era possível antes, mas com a chamada do método `format` das strings, que além de obrigar a escrever mais, obriga a escrever fora da ordem - você põe todo o texto, e depois, nos parâmetros do `.format` vai pensar em quais variáveis vai usar:

Método antigo:

```
nome = "júlia"
idade = 23

print("Olá, {}. Vejo que você tem {} anos.".format(nome, idade)
```

Método novo, com as f-strings:

```
nome = "júlia"
idade = 23

print(f"Olá, {nome}. Vejo que você tem {idade} anos.")
```

(Observe o  `f` antes das `"`)

Assim como no caso do "+", isso é parte da sintaxe da linguagem, e vai funcionar tanto em uma chamada para o print, como em qualquer outro ponto - expressão ou chamada de função no seu código. (A regra é: se a string tem o prefixo `f` para as aspas, como `f"..."`, dentro dela, qualquer texto que vier dentro de `{ }` é executado como código Python, o resultado é convertido em string, e incorporado na string externa.)

Essa forma é interessante por que evita que se tenha que ficar fechando e abrindo `"` a todo o momento, e o código fica muito mais legível e fácil de digitar.

Answer (score 3):

Essas duas formas de se imprimir uma string funcionam perfeitamente e não possuem diferenças no resultado final, porém o processo é sim diferente.

No primeiro caso, você está concatenando a string `"Olá "` com a string `nome` antes de chamar de chamar a função. Logo, isso é equivalente a fazer o seguinte código:

```
print("Olá Júlia")
```

No segundo caso, você está passando as strings separadamente como argumento para a função `print()`, que por sua vez vai juntar as strings com um espaço entre elas para depois imprimi-las na tela.

Comment: É mesmo...tão simples,kkkkk
Sei que o site não gosta de comentários assim,mas muito obrigado!