# Qual a maneira correta de realizar testes de desempenho em Python?

Tags: python

Ao responder essa pergunta [A sintaxe do Python tanto aceita "+" quanto "," no comando "print()"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/429877/a-sintaxe-do-python-tanto-aceita-quanto-no-comando-print/429906?noredirect=1#comment832980_429906) :

[image: Pergunta de referência]

Apresentei a seguinte resposta:

```
Caso sua intenção seja imprimir apenas uma linha, ambos os métodos não possuem diferença. 

Porém se estiver fazendo print em massa dentro de laço, 
por exemplo ao imprimir um relatório, imprimindo uma tabela 
ou imprimindo um planilha. E desempenho é o que importa,
a maneira como você faz a concatenação dos dados pode ser
a diferença entre imprimir os dados no intervalo do cafezinho
ou deixar seus dados sendo impressos durante o almoço.

Fiz o teste de desempenho com alguns tipos de concatenação 
para saber qual é mais rápido:
```

```python
import time

#Concatenar usando o operador +
def função1():
  nome = "Júlia"
  print("Olá " + nome)

#Concatenar usando o próprio print()
def função2():
  nome = "Júlia"
  print("Olá ",nome)

#Concatenar usando formatação de string
def função3():
  nome = "Júlia"
  print("Olá %s" % nome)

#Concatenar usando o método join()
def função4():
  nome = "Júlia"
  print("Olá %s".join([nome]))

#Aguarda 5s para estabilização dos processos de inicialização
time.sleep(5)

#Mede o desempenho da função1()
inicio = time.time()
função1()
print("Concatenado com + levou    %s segundos." % (time.time() - inicio))

#Mede o desempenho da função2()
start_time = time.time()
função2()
print("Concatenado com , levou    %s segundos." % (time.time() - inicio))

#Mede o desempenho da função3()
start_time = time.time()
função3()
print("Concatenado com %% levou    %s segundos." % (time.time() - inicio))

#Mede o desempenho da função3()
start_time = time.time()
função4()
print("Concatenado com join levou %s segundos." % (time.time() - inicio))
```

```
Os resultados foram esses:

Olá Júlia
Concatenado com + levou    0.00017952919006347656 segundos.
Olá  Júlia
Concatenado com , levou    0.0002543926239013672 segundos.
Olá Júlia
Concatenado com % levou    0.0002880096435546875 segundos.
Olá Júlia
Concatenado com join levou 0.0003311634063720703 segundos.
```

Foi me informado, nos comentários, que essa não é a maneira correta de medir o desempenho em python. Então aqui vai a pergunta-titulo, qual a maneira correta de realizar testes de desempenho em Python?

Comment: Quando for algo da linguagem em geral, melhor usar a tag "Python" - "python3.x" pode se ruma tag complementar, e nem ser usada na grande amioria das vezes, já que essa é a versão padrão da linguagem.

Comment: Para deixar claro, qual desempenho estamos falando? Apenas tempo de execução ou gostaria de avaliar utilização de recursos, número de operações, etc?

Comment: @Woss, Seria interessante saber como fazer uma avaliação completa de um fragmento de código.

Comment: @Woss Eu andei pesquisando os módulos [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) . e[`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html), ia ler agora o [`profile`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/profile.html)

Comment: Cara, o teste que esta tentando realizar nessa questão do print e irrelevante, porque digo isso? vamos por parte, o __+ (mais)__ junta as strings, a __, (virgula)__ passar argumentos separados onde o __print__ utilizar digamos o __*args__ para receber uma lista de variáveis e depois jogar e alinhar no print, o restante é manipulação da string por isso leva mais tempo, resumindo, são para uso diferentes que no seu caso tem a mesma saída, é só questão entender o que cada um faz

Comment: Já me falaram isso @GuilhermeFrançadeOliveira, a pergunta é qual a maneira correta de se fazer um teste de performance em python. Outra coisa não é print que está sendo mesurado são as formas de concatenação de strings.

Comment: Sim, por isso deixei apenas um comentário para tentar esclarecer qualquer tipo de duvida, mas não uma reposta, em questão de performance já complica um pouco para responder, como o @Woss disse acima, Qual desempenho..., pois para cada objetivo pode se ter uma reposta e um resultado diferente, são coisas que podem até depender da sua maquina, Tempo de execução? uso de memoria? entre outros. não há um geral, e caso deseje tudo, teria que coletar cada informação separadamente e depois utilizar uma regressão a fim de encontrar uma media entre tudo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essencialmente tens duas formas rápidas para testar a performance de cada método.

Podes optar por usar correr cada função dentro da função [timeit.timeit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

```
def foo():
    # ...

duration = timeit.timeit(foo, number=1000)
```

Caso possas usar `IPython`, tens acesso à função `%timeit`:

```
In [2]: %timeit função1()
773 µs ± 46.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit função2()
278 µs ± 3.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit função3()
135 µs ± 763 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit função4()
126 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Uma questão que levantei na outra resposta era a independência dos testes. Fazê-los juntos dará um resultado diferente do que executar os testes separados. O que pode dizer sobre isso?